# How to wrap image inside text - lists not ordered with text?

Tags: css, image, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to wrap an image inside some text, side by side. I almost did it but there is a small problem with lists:

[image]

There is no problem with paragraphs but lists are pushed a little bit to the left, going under the image. I've tried several things but can't solve the problem:/

Here is the piece of code I'm using:

```
<div class="col-xs-8 pull-right">
    <img class="pull-left" style="margin:0px 10px 10px 0px;width:60%;height:220px;" src="http://kkop.files.wordpress.com/2010/01/usapolice.jpg"/>

    <div class="article-text">content here</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

(Answered by the OP in a question edit. Converted to a community wiki answer. See [Question with no answers, but issue solved in the comments (or extended in chat)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments) )

The OP wrote:

> Since no one helped me, I keept on searching and found a solution.
>
> For everyone with the same problem, add this to `css`:

```
ol{
 padding:0;
 list-style-position:inside;
}
```

> And the problem is solved! ;)